# New Bench Press Rule: How can we modulate our back arch/grip width so that the rep is valid?

Tags: powerlifting, bench-press

Arching the back as much as we can and/or widening the grip reduces the chest range of motion.

However the new powerlifting rules require the elbow being lowered below the shoulder heigth.

Now, since the "current" thoracic mobility of an athlete can also slightly vary from day to day, according to its warm-up, how can we regulate and understand if our current rep is valid or not?

Comment: Considering the amount of red lights I saw in the last IPF meet I watched, I'm not sure the athletes, coaches, and judges know either.